# ImportError: No module named pyorbited.simple while running django-orbited

Tags: python, django, orbited

I am trying to run test project of [django-orbited](http://code.google.com/p/django-orbited/). When I execute `python manage.py runserver`, the following error occurs:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of 
<django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x8ea994c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/prashant/grambox/django-orbited/testing/django_orbited/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyorbited.simple import Client as OrbitedClient
ImportError: No module named pyorbited.simple
```

I have installed orbited using command `pip install orbited`. I tried changing `pyorbited.simple` to `orbited.simple`, but the error persists. Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Value in `sys.path`:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jqmobile-1.0_pre_alpha-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
```

Comment: Have you checked that pyorbited is on your `path`? In python's shell - "import sys; print sys.path"

Comment: Hey Alex, I have updated the question with sys.path values.

Comment: Can you import `pyorbited.simple` from the shell? If not, does `import pyorbited` cause the same error?

Comment: No. I am not able to `import pyorbited.simple` from shell. And `import pyorbited` causes the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed `orbited` but you need to install `pyorbited`.

I can reproduce the same issue with only `orbited` installed:

```
% sudo pip install orbited
% python
>>> import orbited        # yes, this works but it's not what you need
>>> from pyorbited.simple import Client as OrbitedClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyorbited.simple
```

On the other hand, once we install `pyorbited`, it works:

```
% sudo pip install pyorbited
% python
>>> from pyorbited.simple import Client as OrbitedClient
>>>
```